# ASP.NET MVC 5 Authentication based on IIS server's Windows domain

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to create an ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application project that will be accessible through Internet. It will run on an IIS server that belongs to a Windows Domain and already authenticates user through plain HTTP auth for some URLs (accepting domain user accounts).

For my project, I'd like to have a login page that will ask for username and password and authenticate against the same Windows domain. The user won't login with its local Windows domain user. I've found references to similar questions, but using Forms authentication, or ASP.NET 2.0, and I guess it's not the way I should do it using newer infrastructure.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Web Express and, when I create a new Project using .NET Framework 4.5 templates, it allows me to choose between No Authentication, Individual User Accounts, Organizational Accounts or Windows Authentication.

I've researched a lot before asking here but I didn't find any clue about which of the three last options will allow me to configure my app the way I want, although I think that Windows Authentication is restricted only for intranet applications.
In my research, I became aware of System.DirectoryServices.dll, but I'm not sure if this is the way I'd implement the authentication logic.

Any hints / links will be very appreciated, but sample code is always better.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alexandre, welcome to SO. With regards to your question we would need more information to answer your question. You say that your users will be accessing via the internet, but you do not note where the credentials for your users come from (your local AD or another AD). Also, you do not note what sort of workflow you want your users to go through to "log-in", what your security considerations are etc. But my guess is if you are just authenticating users from your local AD, who happen to be connected from outside your network, then just setting auth to `Windows Authentication` will work.

Comment: @Aron: the credential for the users will come from the same Windows Domain Controller (AD, I guess) that is used to authenticate using HTTP auth. Users will authenticate by reaching a login page and inputting username/password, much like HTTP auth dialog, but using a Razor page. I don't know if Windows Authentication is the best choice, because users won't log in with the same username they have for their local domains. It should work just like "Individual User Accounts", except that the users/roles won't be stored in a SQL database, but will be managed through Windows Domain administration.

Comment: Any reason you want to use a login form rather than the browser login? Using the browser is much easier as its just `Windows Auth` over `Basic`, whilst what you say you want requires `On-Premises Organizational Authentication`, which is a little over kill (usually used when you host your website OFF SITE).

Comment: @Aron: Wouldn't `Windows Auth` over `Basic` require HTTPS (for security reasons)? And for `On-Premises Organizational Authentication`, where do I find the required "On-Premises Authority" (metadata document URL)?

Comment: Nope. You can just use `Basic Auth` with HTTP. However it would be utterly insecure (no less secure than your proposal). However, you could also use `Digest Auth`, which IS stronger than forms auth or basic auth.

Comment: @Aron: Yes, I see; if I don't set HTTPS, a login page authentication won't hide username/password, just like Basic Auth. Well, then it looks like I can use `Windows Auth` over `Digest`; so, do I simply choose `Windows Authentication` in project or is there also something to set in `web.config`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that uses the `PrincipalContext` (System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement) to validate domain credentials.

```
public static bool ValidateDomainCredentials(string username, string password)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        return false;
    }

    using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain"))
    {
           return pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
    }
}
```

Call this before signing in to make sure the user is in the active directory.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    ...
    var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
    if (user != null && ValidateDomainCredentials(user.user_Name, model.Password))
    {
        await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
}
```